# Is the leading underscore for the function names for the __stdcall and __cdecl calling conventions optional?

Tags: c, calling-convention

The `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` calling conventions states that the functions names must be preceded by an underscore:

> **C (__cdecl)**
>
> The same constraints apply to the 32-bit world as in the 16-bit world.
>   The parameters are pushed from right to left (so that the first
>   parameter is nearest to top-of-stack), and the caller cleans the
>   parameters. **Function names are decorated by a leading underscore**.
>
> **__stdcall**
>
> This is the calling convention used for Win32, with exceptions for
>   variadic functions (which necessarily use __cdecl) and a very few
>   functions that use __fastcall. Parameters are pushed from right to
>   left [corrected 10:18am] and the callee cleans the stack. **Function
>   names are decorated by a leading underscore** and a trailing @-sign
>   followed by the number of bytes of parameters taken by the function.

I have compiled the following code in Visual C++ (The source file had a `.c` extension, so I guess the source file was compiled as a `C` file):

```
void __stdcall stdcallFunction(int i)
{
    int j = 12345;
}

void __cdecl cdeclFunction(int i)
{
    int j = 12345;
}

int main()
{
    stdcallFunction(123);

    cdeclFunction(123);

    return 0;
}
```

I have noticed that the function names inside the compiled object file did not have a leading underscore:

[image]

Is the leading underscore for the function names for the `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` calling conventions optional?

Comment: As per MS docs, In a 64-bit environment, functions are not decorated.

Comment: It is not optional, it is a link implementation detail.  A failfast for a mismatch in the declaration and the definition of the function.  Such mismatches would otherwise cause very nasty runtime errors due to the stack imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

Name decoration isn't directly related to the calling convention. For the calling convention, it's only important that caller and callee use this same convention, and the compiler can make sure they do if you provide the correct attributes in declarations.

So the name decoration is just *conventional*. It's sometimes useful being able to deduce how to call a function from its decorated name. Therefore, it's good practice to follow the convention when exposing functions from a library. I *assume* you would end up with decorated names if you `dllexport` these functions and link your code into a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

The function decorations are not part of the C standard.

It is something defined in the ABI (Abstract Binary Interface) defined by the development environment used.

Specifically the rules reported in the question are those used by MS.

MS compiler doesn't use by default the C decoration (mangling) unless the function(s) are enclosed in `EXTERN 'C' { ... }` block, or a specific compiler switch is used (typically `-TC`).

And, as already mentioned in another answer, the MS ABI for 64bits code use a different C mangling that doesn't include the underscore prefix.

Comment: I have noticed a strange thing, when creating the object file using the Visual C++ IDE, the function names in the object file won't have a leading underscore. But when creating the object file from the command line (`cl /c main.c`), the function names will have a leading underscore!

Comment: Check, from the project properties, what switches are set ;-)

Comment: These are the switches: `/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oi /Oy- /GL /D "_MBCS" /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\1.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue`. Do you know which switch is responsible for not preceding function names with an underscore?

Comment: No one of these should have influence on decorations. Anyway **If you're compiling for 64bits you'll never get underscore prefix because X64 ABI don't allow it.**